# Good way to aggregate in data.table by a 'group' represented in a column of indicator variables?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` object with various columns of `0`s and `1`s representing different 'scenarios' under which I'd like to aggregate the values of a column. Something like this:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
a <- ifelse(runif(10) < .5, 0, 1)
b <- ifelse(runif(10) < .5, 0, 1)
c <- ifelse(runif(10) < .5, 0, 1)
foo <- data.table(value=rnorm(10),case.a=a, case.b=b, case.c=c)
```

And I'd like, for each "case" to compute, say, the sum of `value` when that case is `1`. I was trying something like this:

```
cases <- names(foo)[grep('case',names(foo))]
sapply(cases, function(case) { foo[,value * case] }
```

which doesn't feel like the right approach and also doesn't work.

Comment: Would this work?  `sapply(foo[, cases, with=F], val=foo[, value], function(x, val) sum(x*val))`

Comment: Neat, returns a list of matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an option that first Reshapes data in long format:

```
melt(foo,id.vars = "value")[value.1==1,sum(value),"variable"]

##    variable        V1
## 1:   case.a  1.551384
## 2:   case.b  3.014265
## 3:   case.c -1.090449
```

Comment: You don't need to load `reshape2` in order to use `melt`. Btw, `data.table` v 1.9.6 is on CRAN.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks.Good catch. Actually I am  using an old version of dt package.

Comment: That's fine, I'm just saying you can update to the newer version from CRAN instead of GH. You'll probably need to build it from source though. As an additional approach, you could do `foo[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(value*x))]` if won't be too picky regarding calculating `value` too.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R `sapply` to return a vector

```
sapply(foo[, ..cases], val=foo[, value], function(x, val) sum(x*val))
   case.a    case.b    case.c 
 1.551384  3.014265 -1.090449
```

And using `data.table`, although I can't figure out how to subset out the first column.

```
foo[, lapply(.SD, function(x, val=value) sum(x*val))]
      value   case.a   case.b    case.c
1: 7.723752 1.551384 3.014265 -1.090449
```

Comment: Oh nice, yea I have quite a few other columns irrelevant to this computation some are not even numeric

Comment: I hesitated to post because I couldn't figure out the subset.  I suppose you could store the initial result and then subset with  `foo <- foo[, lapply(...]` then `foo2 <- foo[, .(case.a, case.b, case.c)]`